# How to set linewidth of axis in 3d plot in python?

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, axis

How to set linewidth of axis in 3d plot in python? Is it somehow possible with mpl.rcParams?
Code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1)
```